# The line its painting the picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a program to make a polygon and fill the outside of it, all of this on an image of a picturebox.

My code is this (I extracted a part of the original and I used and edited the code of **VB Helper: Let the user draw polygons in Visual Basic .NET**)

> ```
> Dim Polygons As New List(Of List(Of Point))()
> Dim NewPolygon As List(Of Point) = Nothing
> Dim NewPoint As Point
> Dim bmp As Bitmap
> ```

```
Private Sub khe_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bmp = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
    PictureBox1.Image = bmp
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    If (NewPolygon IsNot Nothing) Then
        If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Right) Then
            If (NewPolygon.Count > 2) Then _
                Polygons.Add(NewPolygon)
            NewPolygon = Nothing
        Else
            If (NewPolygon(NewPolygon.Count - 1) <> _
                e.Location) Then
                NewPolygon.Add(e.Location)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        NewPolygon = New List(Of Point)()
        NewPoint = e.Location
        NewPolygon.Add(e.Location)
    End If

    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    NewPoint = e.Location
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Using myGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
        For Each polygon As List(Of Point) In Polygons
            Dim gp As New GraphicsPath
            gp.AddPolygon(polygon.ToArray())

            Dim rgn As New Region(gp)

            myGraphics.ExcludeClip(rgn)
            myGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightPink, Me.ClientRectangle)

            myGraphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.SeaShell, polygon.ToArray())
        Next polygon

        If (NewPolygon IsNot Nothing) Then
            If (NewPolygon.Count > 1) Then
                myGraphics.DrawLines(Pens.SeaShell, _
                    NewPolygon.ToArray())
            End If

            If (NewPolygon.Count > 0) Then
                Using dashed_pen As New Pen(Color.Aquamarine, 5)
                    myGraphics.DrawLine(dashed_pen, _
                        NewPolygon(NewPolygon.Count - 1), _
                        NewPoint)
                End Using
            End If
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

The problem is this: Initially I was using e.Graphics and the program was working well, but this does not paint the image, rigth? and I changed it, but when I click to start drawing and I move the mouse to set the next point the line is painting the image wherever I move, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPQ0m.png).
This is bad because I want to get a image [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPhOE.jpg), and with this problem if I move the mouse on the area I want to keep its going to be painted and the image will be useless.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and I'm sorry if my english it's not the best.

Comment: You said it was working with e.Graphics. Why not go back to that and just draw on the form itself. Why do you need a picture box control at all?